# Iterating tags using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a xml structures like below,

`<NameList>
    <Name>name01</Name>
    <Name>name02</Name>
    <Name>name03</Name>
    <Name>name04</Name> 
</NameList>`

how to iterate over the child tags of NameList and display them using XSLT's xsl:for-each? 
My ouput should be like

name01
name02
name03
name04

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not completly sure what you want, but maybe like this?

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="NameList">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>          
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

It puts out

```
    name01 name02 name03 name04
```

Comment: Thx. i got the results.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real need to use **xsl:for-each**. You can do this with template matching which is usually the favoured approach in XSLT.

You would need one template to match your **NameList** element, where you can output any 'containing' elements you want, and then start selecting the child elements

```
  <xsl:template match="NameList">
     <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Name" />
     </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then you have a template actually matching the **Name** element, where you output it in whatever format you want. For example

```
  <xsl:template match="Name">
    <tr>
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT for starters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="NameList">
     <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Name" />
     </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Name">
    <tr>
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you did want any more help with formatting or outputting elements, you really need to have mentioned this in your question. Thanks!